# Try to locate php bin in Red hat

Tags: php

I am connecting through SSH to a Red Hat machine. I am not root. I try to localize the PHP interpreter (in Debian, that would be /usr/bin/php for example) but I don't find it. `which` is not installed and since I'm not root I cannot install rpm packages. I know php is installed because I can type php in terminal and it goes in read mode. I tried `find / -type d -name php` or f`ind / -type f -name ph`p and I got the output "terminated" which I guess means nothing was found. How could I locate php?

Comment: is there maybe an alias set for "php". In Red Hat it should be under /usr/bin/ as well.

Comment: @raffael `ls /usr/bin` or even `ls /usr/local/bin` show no php

Comment: run `alias` and see if an alias has been set up for php.

Comment: @Lain nope, tried `alias` y nothing set for php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can execute `php`, you can get `phpinfo()`. There you have information about interpreter itself.

```
php -i | grep '"_"'
```

Comment: found it! Thanks vartec! It was in an obscure /usr/local subfolder !

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Bash:

```
type -a php
```

Which will tell you all the aliases, functions and executables (that are in your `PATH`) that "php" refers to.

Something similar will work in other shells.

Other commands you can try (besides `which`) are `whereis` and `whence`.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, it did the job! I would have set yours as answer but i already did for vartec's which did the trick too and I don't have enough reputation to vote you up but the feeling is here :)

Answer (score 1):

First check whether php-cli is installed.

```
rpm -qa | grep php-cli
```

Comment: I get the following `error: cannot open Packages index using db3 - Permission denied (13)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm`

Comment: I suppose you have to do that as `root` or similar superuser permissions.

Comment: On my installation I can run it as a normal user, you will have to contact your sysadmin then.